# Кавычки для аббревиатур

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки

Нужно ли брать в кавычки аббревиатуры названий? Например, "Комсомольская правда" — КП или "КП"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь применимо правило: "Пишутся в кавычках аббревиатуры инициального типа, представляющие собой сокращение условного наименования. В их числе: 
названия периодических изданий: «РГ» («Российская газета»), «АиФ» («Аргументы и факты»), «МК» («Московский комсомолец»), «НГ» («Независимая газета»), «СЭ» («Спорт-экспресс») и др". См. http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/?rub=kav3

Answer (score 1):

Если это название газеты, журнала и т.п., у которых есть традиционное сокращение, то кавычки нужны.